# Adding an Object to an existing System Class

Tags: c#, sockets, extension-methods

At the moment I have a problem. I want to expand the `System.Socket` class with a string, where I can store information to the Socket.

For example, adding a variable called Name, but if I write it like that then it won't work because all sockets would have the same name. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem or what would be the easiest way?

```
public static string Name;

public static string getName(this Socket socket)
{
    return Name;
}

public static void setName(this Socket socket, string name)
{
    Name = name;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the whole class where you are extending Socket? Why use a widely used name [Name] for your own purpose? Call it FooName if you want, but Name is just a bad choice.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least a few options here:

- Stick with the extension method approach you're showing in your question.
- Subclass the `Socket` class so that you can add a `Name` property to the type itself.
- Use the ["Decorator Pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to wrap the `Socket` class in your own type that has a `Name` property.

If you want to use an extension method, you'll need to maintain a different `string` value for each `Socket` object. One way to do this is to have a dictionary that maps from `Socket` object references to names. For example:

```
public static Dictionary<Socket, string> _socketNames = new Dictionary<Socket, string>();

public static string getName(this Socket socket)
{
    return _socketNames[socket];
}

public static void setName(this Socket socket, string name)
{
    _socketNames[socket] = name;
}
```

Subclassing would look like this:

```
class SocketEx : Socket
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Wrapping would look like this:

```
class SocketWrapper
{
    public Socket Socket { get; }
    public string Name { set; set; }

    public SocketWrapper(Socket socket)
    {
        Socket = socket;
    }
}
```

With such a vaguely written question it's impossible to know which would be best for your specific needs. Each of the above has its pros and cons. You'll have to decide for yourself which works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used Subclassing now and it works fine. I only knew how i can expand a class with "this" parameter.

Comment: @Silent3241: if your original question has been addressed, consider accepting this answer, or if you feel this one doesn't adequately address your question, posting your own answer and accepting it. That way it will be clear in searches that your question no longer requires an answer. If you are still looking for someone else to post a better answer, please edit your question to explain why the answer you've gotten so far is inadequate and what else it is you're looking for.